# I am trying to use a if statement in a loop but it does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

Before we start I want to apologies in advance for the Swedish names I changed most of them.
So I have created a bag of marbles with three marbles of each colour (blue, red, green) and the specific code I have an issue with is this:

```
if dragning_1 == dragning_2 == dragning_3: three = three + 1
```

If I understood it correctly it only counts once after it´s complete but I would like it to count once per loop. Full code below:

```
import random

def ten_times (n):
  if n > 0:
    three = 0
    marbles = ["blue","blue","blue","red","red","red","green","green,","green"]
    dragning_1 = random.choice(marbles)
    kulpåse.remove(dragning_1)
    dragning_2 = random.choice(marbles)
    kulpåse.remove(dragning_2)
    dragning_3 = random.choice(marbles) 
    if dragning_1 == dragning_2 == dragning_3:
      three = three + 1
    n = n - 1
  print("så här många gånger drog vi tre av samma färg", three, "när vi drog", n + 1 , "gånger")
```

Comment: change if to while

Comment: I fail to see the loop in your code.

Comment: `sum(len(set(random.sample(marbles, 3))) == 1 for _ in range(n))`.

Comment: Where is `kulpåse` defined?

Comment: @Stark - Thanks I changed it to while!

Comment: @Aplet123 - Yeah I think my error was n = n - 1 should have just been ten_times (n - 1).

Comment: @ekhumoro - Maybe it is my inexperience but I don´t really know what you are after with that line of code, or where I should place it. Thanks for the feedback though! :)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - Lost in swedish translation there I think. kulpåse = marbles

Comment: Okay, so. The goal is to choose three separate elements from the list? That is indeed what `random.sample` is for.

Comment: @RoderickGunnarssonJohansson It creates `n` random triplets from `marbles` and adds up how many of them are all the same. So it makes exactly the same calculation as your function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to understand the construct of if and while -

IF: if the condition (n>0) is met : DO

WHILE: as long as the condition is met: DO

In the latter case, the code runs n times.

```
  import random

def ten_times (n):
    three = 0
    counter = n
    while counter > 0:
        marbles = ["blue","blue","blue","red","red","red","green","green,","green"]
        dragning_1 = random.choice(marbles)
        marbles.remove(dragning_1)
        dragning_2 = random.choice(marbles)
        marbles.remove(dragning_2)
        dragning_3 = random.choice(marbles) 
        if dragning_1 == dragning_2 == dragning_3:
            three+= 1
        counter-=1
    print("så här många gånger drog vi tre av samma färg", three, "när vi drog", n , "gånger")
```

Also please use a counter variable.

Comment: No Problem, I would be glad if you accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a bit more complicated than that. First issue was it did not loop properly. Fixed by changing `n = n - 1` into `n-=1`. @KaRaOkEy don´t worry I will start using a counter variable. :)

The next issue was the actual counting which needed two major changes to fix:
First `if n > 0:` was changed to `while n > 0:`
Secondly I had an issue actually printing it since three was only a value within the definition. I solved it by adding this line of code in the end of definition of ten_times `else: print("this many times we got three", three)`